# How to validate email with pattern in service

Tags: angular6

I am validate my email in service.ts I am checking null and blank value but i want check pattern also if any one has any solution please share me.Thank you

```js
if (item.ClientEmail1 == null || item.ClientEmail1 == '') {
      validation += '<li>' + this.messages.vld_ClientEmail1 + '</li>';
      isSuccess = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
static email(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} {
    if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value)) {
      return null;
    }
    const regex = /^(([^/<>()\\\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^/<>()\\\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^/<>()\\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;


    const v: string = control.value;
    return regex.test(v) ? null : {'email': true};
  }
```